# To add a value entered in a field to select list

Tags: 7

I have a field and select list. When a value is entered in the field ,if that value is  not present in the select list then i want to append that value in the select list.
how can i acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the workflow you're looking for but one of these two modules can help you:

- **[Select or Other](http://drupal.org/project/select_or_other)**

> Provides a new Forms API element which is a select/radios/checkboxes
>   element that has an 'other' option. When 'other' is selected a
>   textfield appears for the user to provide a custom value.

- **[Multiple Selects](http://drupal.org/project/multiple_selects)**

> Rather than having a multi-select field, this modules allows you to
>   have multiple select fields with the traditional FieldAPI 'Add another
>   item' button.

Comment: Select or Other : This was really close one but it would be better if I could add the value entered in other field to select list permanently.So that next time the form is accessed the select list will have that value.